# Controlling the i18n language in jinja2 / coffin without passing a request every time

Tags: python, django, internationalization, jinja2

I am trying to render a template to a string in a particular language, but without passing the request or RequestContext to render_to_string every time.  I'm using

```
coffin.shortcuts.render_to_string
```

So I want to either just include a variable in the dictionary, or a fake context that will be ignored except as far as language goes.

I can make it work by sending the request, but that is just overkill - these are asynchronous processes, so I don't even have a request available sometimes.

I've looked at the code in django translations, coffin, & jinja2 & it's extremely complicated.  I've also tried just sending LANGUAGE or LANGUAGE_CODE as part of the dictionary, with no results.

If I modify the source of the RequestContext class to only include csrf & i18n modules, coffin's render_to_string obeys the browser language.

I created a FakeRequestContext class:

```
class FakeRequestContext(Context):
    def __init__(self, request, dict_=None, processors=None, current_app=None,
            use_l10n=None, use_tz=None):
        Context.__init__(self, dict_, current_app=current_app,
                use_l10n=use_l10n, use_tz=use_tz)
        from django.utils import translation
        context_extras = {}
        from django.conf import settings
        context_extras['LANGUAGES'] = settings.LANGUAGES
        context_extras['LANGUAGE_CODE'] = translation.get_language()
        if 'LANGUAGE_CODE' in dict_:
            context_extras['LANGUAGE_CODE'] = dict_['LANGUAGE_CODE']
        context_extras['LANGUAGE_BIDI'] = translation.get_language_bidi()
        self.update(context_extras)
```

which seems to exactly reproduce what RequestContext is doing, but does not actually work, even though LANGUAGE_CODE is being set to what it would be from the browser when using the real RequestContext.

Comment: it also seems that django / jinja2 is messing around with stack frames to make debugging templates easier.  However, this is making it impossible to actually find the place it figures out what language to i18n the template.

Comment: I am also fighting the same problem, would say it doesn't seems a good idea to wrap the RequestContext, since coffin must have done that anyways - There must have been some gotcha !

Comment: solved by just importing django.utils.translation.activate and activating the language I want...